Doubt on the $\int_{|z|=1} f(z) dz$
Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in the unit disc $
|z| < 1$ and continuous on the boundary of the unit disc. Can we say that $\int_{|z|=1} f(z) dz = 0$?
I know that for $r>0$, $\int_{|z|=r} f(z) dz = 0$ as $f$ is holomorphic in $|z| < 1$ but I don't know what can we say about $\int_{|z|=1} f(z) dz$?

Yes. Use uniform continuity of $f$ to prove that the sequence of functions $f_n(z)=f\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)z\right)$ converges unifromly to $f$, and deduce the conclusion.

@Math101 Ah I got it. Thank you so much

Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1541079/96384 and comments to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1123090/96384.

@Aruralreader someone down voted my question. So I thought it was maybe because of that
